# Почему Intellije Idea на этапе Build не переиспользует результат компиляции сделанный Maven

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

На сайте JetBrains Help прочитал что Intellij Idea на этапе Build не переиспользует результат компиляции сделанный мавеном, а билдит все с нуля.

В разделе **Use Maven output directories** написано

If this checkbox is not selected, the build will be created in the regular IntelliJ IDEA's output directory USER_HOME\IdeaProjects<project>\classes\Production. If this checkbox is selected, the build is generated in the Maven's output directory, and the results of IntelliJ IDEA's compilation are reused. **However, IntelliJ IDEA itself does not reuse Maven build results, and performs compilation from scratch.**

[JetBrains Help Importing Maven](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.1/maven-importing.html?utm_campaign=IU&utm_content=2020.1&utm_medium=link&utm_source=product)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intellije IDEA не переиспользует данные классы скомпилированные мавеном потому что имеет собственную систему инкрементной компиляции, которая отслеживает зависимости между компилируемыми файлами и перекомпилирует минимальный набор классов для каждого набора изменений.

[Intellij Idea compiler recompiles already compiled project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943106)

Если надо, то можно делегировать компиляцию мавену, для этого отметить File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner | Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven.

При изменении веток и если в новой ветке окажется более старый файл чем был в предыдущей ветке то IDE его не подхватит, в этом случае надо запускать либо mvn clean либо в меню Build -> Rebuild Project